# When does force:recordData execute?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, quickaction, force-recorddata

I am using `force:recordData` to pull data for a `Campaign` on load of the component. The component is triggered by a quick action.

I understand that force:recordData is an asynchronous process. However does it execute as soon as the component that contains it loads?

I am getting inconsistent results.

Here's the code that I have in my component:

```
<aura:component controller="MyController" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object" />

    <force:recordData aura:id="smartListRecord"
                recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                targetRecord ="{!v.record}"
                targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
                fields="Id, Name"/>
<lightning:button label="Test"
                          onclick="{!c.testMethod}"/>
```

My JS controller:

```
({
    testMethod: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Record Id:');
        console.log(component.get("v.recordId"));
        console.log('Record:');
        console.log(component.get("v.record"));
    }
})
```

I get the `recordId` but I can't see the `record`. What am I doing wrong?

Sometimes in the console I would get `Proxy{}` with a [[Handler]] and [[Target]] where the [[Target]] would hold the information about the campaign.

Other times the [[Target]] would come in as blank only holding a **proto** no matter how long I wait before I press the button.

Why is this happening?

Comment: what do you mean with, I cannot see the record? any errors? what do you see in your console output?

Comment: As far as I understand force:recordData does not necessarily load the record right when the component is initialized. Usually there is a very little time gap between when the is initialized and force:recordData gets loaded and the framework automatically fires an event whenever the record gets loaded or updated or deleted etc. You can handle these events by adding "recordUpdated" attribute to the force:recordData element and associating it with a Controller Function.Look at the example here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_load_record.htm

Comment: @Nihar - That's how I initially did it and I got the same result. I will update my answer with what I get in the console.

Comment: @Nihar @glls - I understand that `force:recordData` is asynchronous. However does it start pulling data as soon as the page gets loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to correctly output a log of anything `force:recordData` does, you need to wait for it to resolve fully. Luckily, we have an attribute we can listen to, the `recordUpdated` attribute.

This should work:

**Component**

```
<force:recordData aura:id="smartListRecord"
            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            targetRecord ="{!v.record}"
            targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
            recordUpdated="{! c.handleRecordChanged }"
            fields="Id, Name"/>
```

**Controller**

```
handleRecordChanged: function(component, event, helper) {
  switch(event.getParams().changeType) {
    case "ERROR":
      // handle error
      break;
    case "LOADED":
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.record"))));
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.simpleRecord"))));
      console.log(component.get("v.simpleRecord")["Name"]);
      break;
    case "REMOVED":
      // stuff
      break;
    case "CHANGED":
      // more stuff
      break;
  }
}
```

FYI, you can debug properties like this: `component.get("v.simpleRecord")["Name"]`

[Further reading for Lightning Data Service handling Record Changes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_handling_record_change.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but even with that the [[Target]] is coming in as blank. I am working in a scratch org(sfdx) so I wonder if it has something to do with permissions.

Comment: @Arthlete - what happens if you write `{! v.simpleRecord.Name }` directly in the component somewhere? It should output `Name`. As you have it, you're not even telling LDS to grab more fields than Id and Name. Perhaps add more fields?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do. Just not printing it right.

Try this:

```
({
    testMethod: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Record Id:');
        console.log(component.get("v.recordId"));
        console.log('Record:');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.record"), null, 2));
})
```

Comment: @Arthlete and FYI, if you do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.record"))` you can use the collapse and expand in debug to see the nested items easier if you try to debug a JS Object

Comment: @tsalb - Yes you are correct. However sometimes I get content inside [[Target]] which is an object holding the Campaign's data and sometimes [[Target]] comes in as blank. I am not sure what is causing this inconsistent behavior.